# Como Listar produtos de um só Distribuidora MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Tenho uma aplicação que gerencia a Distribuidora e seu Produtos.
Quero listar apenas os produtos da Distribuidora que selecionei, mas no caso esta aparecendo tudo.

Tentei fazer assim:

```
public ActionResult ListarProdutosDistribuidoras(int? id)
{    
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }
    Produto produto = db.Produtos.Find(id);
    if (produto == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    var produtos = db.Produtos.Include(p => p.Pessoa.PessoaID);
    return View(produtos.ToList());
}
```

Comment: a distribuidora é chave primária?

Comment: Opa, sim a distribuidora é chave primária.

Comment: o código tá nebuloso, o que seria este id que ele recebe como parametro e qual campo é a distribuidora ai? Pessoa seria a distribuidora?

Comment: O produto tem o código da distribuidora em que o mesmo pertence? Poste os Models Produto e Distribuidora, para vermos como está o relacionamento.

Answer (score 0):

Suponho que seu *Model* `Produto` seja algo assim:

```
public class Produto
{
    [Key]
    public int ProdutoId { get; set; }
    public int DistribuidoraId { get; set; }

    ...

    public virtual Distribuidora Distribuidora { get; set; }
}
```

Suponho também que sua *Action* receba um `DistribuidoraId` como parâmetro:

```
public ActionResult ListarProdutosDistribuidoras(int? id)
{
    if (id == null)
    {
        return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
    }

    var idNaoNulo = (int)id; // Você já conferiu se é nulo, então posso fazer isso.
    var distribuidora = db.Distribuidoras.FirstOrDefault(d => d.DistribuidoraId == idNaoNulo);
    // Produto produto = db.Produtos.Find(id);

    if (distruibuidora == null)
    {
        return HttpNotFound();
    }

    // Não entendi isso aqui. Acho que falta entendimento sobre o Include.
    // var produtos = db.Produtos.Include(p => p.Pessoa.PessoaID);
    var produtos = db.Produtos.Where(p => p.DistribuidoraId == idNaoNulo);
    return View(produtos.ToList());
}
```